# Code generation using yacc

Tags: code-generation, yacc

Suppose the grammar is given, how to design the code generation process?

```
start(res)       ::= template. { **how to write stuff here?? Is it true there will only be 

one correct way to write this? And Let's suppose the programming language is also given** }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question, with many books an articles written on it.  The general heading you're looking for is [Syntax directed translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax-directed_translation), and the classic reference is the [Dragon Book](http://dragonbook.stanford.edu/)